# Using Addthis in fullscreen mobile web app on iOS

Tags: web-applications, mobile, hyperlink, window, addthis

I've got a web app http://aspekt.vni.io.

It is a fullscreen app and I've integrated addthis. When I click one of the services it loads the share page for the service, but appears to replace the web app. When you add the app to your home screen If you click the Very Nice logo at the top it will open safari and go to the correct web page. However, if you click one of the addthis links it stays on the same page. Is there any way to force it to open in safari or at the very least open in an iframe over the same page as a modal?

thanks,
Howie